# Expressive Power of Second-Order Logic vs. Higher-Order Logics

Tags: logic, higher-order-logic

My question regards the expressive power of second-order logic as compared with third-order logic. Throughout, I am working in the standard or full semantics of higher-order logics (so not the Henkin semantics).

---

**My question is this:** are there third-order formulas $\varphi$ and models $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_2$ such that $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_2$ agree on all second-order formulas but $\mathcal{M}_1 \vDash \varphi$ while $\mathcal{M}_2 \nvDash \varphi$? That is, is third-order logic strictly more expressively powerful than second-order logic?

---

Any reference pointers would be highly appreciated! I've looked through the standard sources (e.g., Shapiro's *Foundations without Foundationalism* Chp. 6, [the entry in the Handbook of Phil Logic](https://staff.science.uva.nl/j.vanbenthem/docs/HOL.pdf), [the SEP article](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#4), etc.) but with no luck. It is a well-known result from Hintikka that there's an effective translation $\tau$ from third-order logic to second-order logic such that for any $\varphi$ in third-order logic, $\varphi$ is valid iff $\tau(\varphi)$ is valid. These sources cite this theorem, but this doesn't quite answer the question posed above, since the proof doesn't require checking $\neg\varphi$'s satisfiability and $\tau(\neg\varphi)$'s satisfiability in the same model. Apparently there's also a theorem stating that the smallest cardinal not describable by an $n$th-order logic is describable by the $n+1$th-order logic. If someone could point to a reference where this is proven, that would be great. But how big is this cardinal? Are we even guaranteed the existence of such undescribable cardinals for second-order logic? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Hi!)

Yes, model-by-model third-order logic is strictly stronger than second-order logic (and similarly for $n$ and $n+1$).

Since you mention it, I'll sketch the route via ordinals (and when I refer to an ordinal $\gamma$, I mean the linear order $(\gamma, \in)$). First, note that all the logics we're looking at are *set-sized*: for any language (= set of nonlogical symbols) $\Sigma$, there are set-many - in fact, $(\aleph_0\cdot\vert\Sigma\vert)$-many - second-order, third-order, etc. formulas. This means that there are only set-many second- or third-order *theories* in a given language; so since there is a proper class of structures in any language, we're always going to have indistinguishable structures.

For instance, for $\mathcal{L}_n$ = $n$th-order logic, there are at most continuum-many ordinals $\alpha$ which are characterized by their $\mathcal{L}_n$-theory (that is, such that for all ordinals $\beta$, $Th_{\mathcal{L}_n}(\alpha)=Th_{\mathcal{L}_n}(\beta)\iff \alpha=\beta$). And there are at most countably many ordinals which are characterized (amongst all ordinals) by some single $\mathcal{L}_n$-sentence.

---

Now, as to the meat of your question, here's a sketch of an answer. $\mathcal{L}_n$-equivalence can be described via higher-order Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse games - just play the corresponding usual EF-game on the iterated powersets of the structures in question. It's not too nasty to use this characterization to show that there is a sentence $\varphi$ of $\mathcal{L}_{n+1}$ such that an ordinal $\beta$ satisfies $\varphi$ iff $\beta$ is $\mathcal{L}_n$-equivalent to some proper initial segment. This then lets us describe - in $\mathcal{L}_{n+1}$ - the least $\beta$ which is $\mathcal{L}_n$-equivalent to some smaller ordinal. But then we're done.

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful.  (Hi!)